# IIS 7 URL Rewrite to GeoServer running on Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, iis, iis-7, rewrite, url

I'm building a mapping application based on OpenLayers that uses GeoServer to serve up mapping data. The problem I'm having is that besides the map images I'm requesting through WMS, I'm using jQuery AJAX to get information from GeoServer. As GeoServer is running on a different port, my requests are being blocked due to cross-site scripting security policies in JavaScript.

As a Java application, **GeoServer runs on Apache on port 8080, while my IIS instance is running on port 80**. Instead of building a proxy, I've decided to **use URL Rewriting in IIS7** to fix this problem. I'm following [this guide](http://www.cartoninjas.net/post/2010/10/12/Installing-GeoServer-on-Windows-7-(x32-or-x64)-and-IIS-75.aspx), but it's still not working. Here are my URL Rewrite rule settings:

- **Matches URL**: `(.*)`
- **Condition**: `{HTTP_URL}` matching `/geoserver`
- **Action**: rewrite to `http://localhost:8080/{R:1}`, appending query string

When I request `http://localhost/geoserver/wms?QUERY_LAYERS=SanDiego:FWSA_sandiego&LAYERS=SanDiego:FWSA_sandiego&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&FEATURE_COUNT=20&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&EXCEPTIONS=application/vnd.ogc.se_xml&BBOX=-13009123.590156,3862057.2905992,-13006066.109025,3865114.7717302&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&x=20&y=20&width=40&height=40&srs=EPSG:900913`, however, all I get is a 404, although the same request on port 8080 returns the proper result.

**What am I doing wrong?** *Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the condition, try {URL} instead of {HTTP_URL}, and for the action make sure that it's a redirect rather than a rewrite.

Comment: I've switched to `{URL}` but I'm not looking for redirection, as that would make all my requests to that port 80 URL be transformed into port 8080 requests, which leads to my requests being blocked due to cross-site scripting security policies in JavaScript.

Comment: Try out Application Request Routing (ARR). http://www.iis.net/download/ApplicationRequestRouting.  That adds the reverse proxy to URL Rewrite so it will front the URL while processing a different site on the back end.

Answer (score 0):

Is the same rule picking up the request for 8080 and trying to rewrite it ad infinitum? Though I suppose a timeout or a querystring length error would be the expected outcome if it were, rather than a 404.

Are you using Failed Request Tracing? Using Fiddler? Tracing http.sys?

Comment: No, I don't think it's picking up :8080 requests, but I'll try it out and report back. I'm using Fiddler, but it's not telling me anything about what's going on inside IIS. As for Failed Request Tracing, I've enabled it but the log directory is empty. How do you trace http.sys?

Thanks!